# Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am facing the following warning when I run my Spring boot project,

```
DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
```

I am facing this issue once i update my project with Maven 3.8.6. I am assuming this problem has to do with the Maven settings. I tried creating a new project and it works fine until I update the build with Maven.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

in my project .classpath file there was a rule that excludes all the sources under src/main/resources. i removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can help anyone going forward, this was my issue most of the time because somehow, I created a resources folder inside the src/main/resources and placed my template folder there. I have figured out why when we start a new application, and we receive this WARN in spring boot:

Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/

The full warning:

```
[WARN[0;39m [35m32536[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ restartedMain][0;39m [36mion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
```

This is an IDE issue with Eclipse. Eclipse looks for your templates in the resource folder like they should. However, if you create a template folder inside a resource folder instead of on the class path of src/main/resources, it will not find it or will have a difficult time finding the Request Mapping(). I have attached some images to show you the example. Sorry new guy and they will not let me display my pictures, but here are the links:

[Picture one Lists the templates folder in a resources folder under src/main/resources. Path: /src/main/resources/resources/templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Sch.png)

[Picture two shows the path as confirmation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW7rT.png)

[Picture three shows the path of what it should be: /src/main/resources/template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzkOb.jpg)

[Picture four is the correct Package Explore tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIrlB.jpg)